# Why is ADB Over WIFI Not Working on Android 10

Tags: android, adb, wifi, android-10.0

I just updated 2 test devices to Android 10 and ADB over WIFI stopped working. Devices are Nokia 7.1 and Galaxy 10. WIFI ADB still works fine for other test devices Android 9 and lower.

Does anyone know how to get it working again or is this something that was removed in Android 10?

Comment: Hey mate, did you ever figure this one out? Running into the same on my devices. The plugins for AS don't work, and manually setting up a connection doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Nope, did lots of searching for this issue but couldn't find anything concrete. The only thing that I found was that some manufacturers disabled ADB over WIFI in Android 10 updates due to security risks. I eventually just gave up and went back to using USB for Android 10 test devices. Would be good to have a working solution though.